# help with multi dimentional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, session

i am building a shopping cart and cant figure out how to store something like this into a session.

```
[product_id1] = quantity;
[product_id1] = size
[product_id1] = color;

[product_id2] = quantity;
[product_id2] = size;
[product_id2] = color;
...
etc
```

so when a user select the quantity of a product then selects its color then selects to add to a cart i want the items selected to be added into a session and each item added to the cart , its attributes selected to be added into a session. how would i do this?

many many thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to store the array into a session or are you asking how to make multi-dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['productid1']['quantity'] = 15;
$_SESSION['productid1']['size'] = 30;
$_SESSION['productid1']['color'] = 'red';

$_SESSION['productid2']['quantity'] = 35;
$_SESSION['productid2']['size'] = 2;
$_SESSION['productid2']['color'] = 'blue';
```

Don't forget to put `session_start()` at the beginning of every page to carry the sessions through the pages.

Comment: What happens when you want a productid1 in red and another productid1 in green?

Comment: wont be possible productid1 is actually an id of a product. so all attribs selected for product1 are selected through html fields. but then updated when a user selects otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. If the customer wants to buy two widgets with the same product_id (one in red, and another in green) then it wont work. The color will be overwritten as the second choice, and the customer won't get what they want.

Comment: oh, your right. thanks for pointing that out. i am having a big problem with understanding multi arrays even though i have studied and worked with it multiple times. can we talk on an instant messaging program by any chance? i use aim my screen name is sarmenhb

Comment: actually i thought about it anad it would only replace the added value if i checked to see if that value existed and updated it with thet new one. but if i just appended another product id that existed into the array then i would be fine.

Comment: I was under the impression that productid1/productid2 were just instances of various products, whether it was the same or different. Same way, the user can add a $_SESSION['productid1']['productID'] value of what the actual product is.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array in session array for your products:

$_SESSION['products'] = Array();

then you can put products there like this:

```
$product = Array();
$product['quantity'] = 6;
$product['size'] = 'XXL';
$product['color'] = 'blue';

$_SESSION['products'][] = $product;

$product = Array();
$product['quantity'] = 2;
$product['size'] = 'XL';
$product['color'] = 'blue';

$_SESSION['products'][] = $product;
```

this will give you numbered array, if you want an associative array, you will just put identifier into []:

```
$_SESSION['products']['productID'] = $product;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$item[$catalog_number]['quantity'] = 1;
$item[$catalog_number]['size'] = 'XL';
$item[$catalog_number]['color'] = 'yellow';
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
unset($item);
```

Repeat for each item you are adding. Alternatively you could do:

```
$item['catalog_number'] = 'ABC-123';
$item['quantity'] = 1;
$item['size'] = 'XL';
$item['color'] = 'yellow';
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
unset($item);
```

Both will work, just make sure you are consistent. Use only one or the other.

Comment: As @Duniyadnd said, put session_start() at the beginning of every page. Assigning to the $_SESSION variable then puts it in the session.